# Delete SQL Query

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008, sql-delete

I want to delete rows of a column on the basis of condition of another column.  For example:

```
DELETE FROM table_name column_name WHERE another_column_name='some value';
```

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: What database are you using?

Comment: I am using Sql Server 2008

Comment: What do you mean by "delete rows of a column" ?

Comment: The appearance of column_name prior to the WHERE clause is a syntax error.

Comment: as delete query deletes all row I want to delete only one cell

Comment: Blank it? Set it to zero? Give us something to work on :)

Comment: If you want to reset a specific column, use an update rather than a delete.

Comment: You can delete the sql query by selecting the query and pressing backspace.

Comment: @EricLeschinski Thats not the way to answer a question

Comment: I'm answering your question perfectly.  You don't want to delete the SQL query?

Comment: Where i mentioned that

Comment: Yahoo answers has a really good user base for helping people with these sorts of questions:  see here: http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080820174408AAZkbcG

Comment: thanks for your advise but it will not work here

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you mean "delete the column", you can set it to `null`:

```
UPDATE table_name SET
column_name = null
WHERE another_column_name = 'some value'
```